# Avoid reload when taking Back button to homepage

Tags: discussion, homepage, caching, internet-explorer-8

Sometimes a question on the homepage catches my eye just as I've clicked something else, and by the time I've clicked Back to return to the homepage it's disappeared from view.

I'd prefer it if, when I hit Back, I'd get the historical version of the homepage I was on before, not the absolute most up-to-date one; if I want that, I can just hit the logo on whatever page I've navigated to.

Is SO deliberately telling my browser to not cache the homepage, and if so, can it be changed?

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome... maybe your browser isn't caching? Anyway you can always middle click links in homepage to open them in new tab.

Comment: Do you mean it goes back to its initial state, before it was updated via AJAX?

Comment: Most times I do middle-click if I see several questions I want, it's the odd occasion where I just see one so open it alone, then notice another one just before the page switches. I wonder whether it's something browser-specific then... @hayden I don't know about AJAX, it just gives me a new list of questions, rather than the one that was on it when I navigated away.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd If it is my browser, it's also something to do with SE... I checked in Fiddler. If I go to Google, click something, and then press Back, I don't get a repeat request for `/`, whereas if I go to SO, click a question, and then press back, I _do_ get a repeat request for `/`.